# To come to him in a breeze

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms

Acording to the [The Free Dictionary,](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+breeze) the phrase *in a breeze* has this meaning:

> Easily; handily; without much or any effort.

I thought the phrase could be used as this:

> The answer came to him in a breeze.

However, Google threw [zero results](https://www.google.com.tw/search?client=ubuntu&hs=Jh9&ei=OC6JXP_HN8Of8QXtwryIBw&q=%22came%20to%20him%20in%20a%20breeze%22&oq=%22came%20to%20him%20in%20a%20breeze%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1117.1692..1882...0.0..0.45.242.6......0....1..gws-wiz.......33i10.w9LnAwK43ug).

Dose this mean the idiom can't be used like this?

Comment: A related example sentence is [*travelling through London was a breeze*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/breeze).

Comment: I think the phrase works well. It is like "the idea came to me [out of the blue](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out-of-the-blue)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to explain how ***in a breeze*** is used and when it can't be used, partly because it's not that widely used. It's generally used for success at something, and something done actively - "they won in a breeze" is a much-referred to example, though I'm not sure how common it is in actual usage. Most Google results for it are it being used as an example. In that case, it means that they won both easily and decisively, such as by a wide margin of victory. It mostly seems to get used in sporting contexts. Your example is not a natural or idiomatic use of anything.

"It was a breeze!" is a more commonly used term, in my experience, to mean something was easily achieved.

Now, "it came to him on a breeze", that would be poetic language, suggesting the idea just drifted gently to him with no effort on his part. That's not using the same idiom, though.

Comment: They won in a breeze is a much referred to example? ***Winning was a breeze.***

Comment: @Lambie, I noted that was more common. And yes, there's a surprising number of references to "they won in a breeze" and similar. Much more references than actual uses, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Lambie - It isn’t too difficult to verify the assertion that _”they won in a breeze”_ is indeed a much-referred-to example. I just Googled “won in a breeze”, and most of the first page of hits was taken from dictionary pages explaining the idiom. Moreover, the next page of hits showed the expression used in contemporary news articles – mostly from sports pages, but not exclusively: _Both men, Douglas and Cruz, should have won in a breeze. They didn’t._ (Politico, Dec 2018). It may not be an oft-heard phrase, but this answer is spot on.